# ExecuteScalar return 0 value

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a function and a procedure which check a record is exist in database or not.It supposes to get 1 when the record exists and 0 not exist. I executed my procedure It works properly but in visual studio doesn't work.I couldn't find the problem
here is my procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkRepititiveModel]
@modelName nvarchar(50)
as
If EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  models WHERE modelName = @modelName)
begin 
return 1
end
Else 
begin 
return 0
end
```

and below is my function:

```
 public int CheckRepetitive(string connectionString,string modelName)
        {
            SqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            if (SqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("checkRepititiveModel", SqlCon);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modelName", modelName);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            int result = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
            if (SqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                SqlCon.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

and I check with this if statment in main form

```
int a = Db.CheckRepetitive(ConStr, txtBxModelName.Text);
            if (a > 0)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString() + " exist!!");
                return;
            }
```

Comment: "ExecuteScholar" sounds like some real barbaric, anti-education action

Comment: You should be careful with `AddWithValue`, it is fine in this specific case but there are situations where [it can cause you to not use indexes in your database if it chooses the wrong type](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), it is better to use `Add` and pass in a type.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you should SELECT something, so the ExecuteScalar can retrieve the first element of your rowset. Alter your SP and do SELECT instead of RETURN. Something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkRepititiveModel]
  @modelName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  Catalogo.Maquina WHERE Codigo = @modelName)
      SELECT 1
  ELSE 
    SELECT 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the return value of the procedure you need to create a parameter you bind to the `ReturnValue` direction.

Also, you really should be making the connection local to the function and disposing of it using a `using` statement.

```
 public int CheckRepetitive(string connectionString,string modelName)
 {
    using(var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("checkRepititiveModel", sqlCon);
        com.Parameters.Add("@modelName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = modelName;

        SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@rc", SqlDbType.Int);
        retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return (int)retval.Value;
    }
}
```